# How to fix Error:Could not find com.google.gms: google-services: 3.0.0.?

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to add firebase addmob in my app.

In build.gradle(Project) i have following code

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

In build.gradle(module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myname.examp.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase: firebase-ads: 9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have updated version of google play service and repository

[image]

When I sync project still i am getting following error

```
Error:Could not find com.google.gms: google-services: 3.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio2/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/ google-services/ 3.0.0/ google-services- 3.0.0.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio2/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/ google-services/ 3.0.0/ google-services- 3.0.0.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/ google-services/ 3.0.0/ google-services- 3.0.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/ google-services/ 3.0.0/ google-services- 3.0.0.jar
Required by:
    :MyApplication:unspecified
```

Can some one help me how to fix this error

Comment: Have you added `google-services.json` in your app folder.

Comment: @AmanJain.Please add this in answer so i can accept your answer.Thanks a lot for your answer.I thought google-services.json is not required while installing library

Comment: Whoever given vote down please tell me why.so i can improve next time.I have explained my question as good as possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please add `google-services.json` in your app folder.

Comment: This does not work for me, even after adding google-service.json file. It still give same error.

Comment: This file isn't mentioned anywhere on the instructions with setting up GA. 
 Where do I get this file?

Comment: @marty Goto Firebase Console > Overview > Project Setting > Download google-services.json

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 18):

I had similar problem, I copied the dependency from the firebase instructions and pasted in code.

From instructions:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 3.0.0'
```

Supposed to be:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Should not include any spaces. Silly but wasted half an hour.

Comment: I have copy pasted from Firebase 
Issue: com.google.gms.google-services
Right:com.google.gms:google-services (colon after gms not dot)

Answer (score 3):

Add the class path line in the top level gradle file. Not in the same file where you add individual dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Move class path dependency to project level `build.gradle` file as follows :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

and ensure that the apply plugin line after dependencies in your build.gradle file in app folder as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I made a silly mistake. I had `apply from: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` instead of `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.

Answer (score 0):

add the classpath in the build.gradle at your project level not the one in module level.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.+'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

and then apply it in the module level.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

I had solved the problem by changing

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'`

to

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'`

Maybe you need to downgrade version

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue with **flutter** project for
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

For Instance of firebase in app

1. Go to Firebase Project Click on Flutter Cli
2. Add firebase cli package in your system
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli?authuser=0&hl=en#install_the_firebase_cli

```
    curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash 
    dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
    firebase login
    flutterfire configure --project=projectId
```

3. Add firebase to your project for android/ios

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue with **flutter** project for
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

For Instance of firebase in app

1. Go to Firebase Project Click on Flutter Cli or go run below steps
2. Add firebase cli package in your system
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli?authuser=0&hl=en#install_the_firebase_cli

```
    curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash 
    dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
    firebase login
    flutterfire configure --project=projectId
```

3. Add firebase to your project for android/ios

Answer (score -2):

Error:org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs$TaskInputUnionFileCollection cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.