# Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:9.0.0 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

> WAIT. I know what you're thinking. Before you mark this as a 'duplicate', you need to know that ALL of the other posts I've seen have terrible answers that absolutely do not work for me. They might be outdated, I'm not sure, but all I know is that they don't work

So I have my gradle build in 'app'. It looks something like this:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.oneclicklearn.fastchat"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:messaging:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:auth:3.1.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I can include a screenshot here as well. You can see ALL my files here:

[Go to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgZ6i.png)

Now I will list the links that seem to be unhelpful:

- [Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:9.0,0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611298/could-not-find-com-google-gmsgoogle-services9-0-0)
  This question is outdated
- [How to fix Error:Could not find com.google.gms: google-services: 3.0.0.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554608/how-to-fix-errorcould-not-find-com-google-gms-google-services-3-0-0)
  This question's answers simply did not work

I hope this was enough info for you. Feel free to comment if you need me to say more!

Comment: A few observations. Your firebase gradle dependences are old - why?. Also actually edit your question to list out the links you've looked at, what you did (and how it didn't solve your problem). While this does sound tedious it would remove any doubt as to your efforts.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for the input! I'll make those changes in a bit. Also, I had no idea that my gradle dependencies were old, and I'm wondering if you could tell me how to fix that. I would appreciate it if you were patient with me as I am very new to this.

Comment: For the list of gradle modules see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries

Comment: @MorrisonChang  Excuse me, but how can this help my issue? My issue is with apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37312564/295004 which can be found by following your first link - can you show what is in your root build.gradle file.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Nope. Nothing seems to work