# Android app with firebase implementation

Tags: android, firebase

How to fix "Could not find com.google.gms:google-services3.0.o " Even after adding json file and[google-services.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aOOI.png) applying plugin for it

This is where i applied plugin for google services  [image: Image Here]

[Classpath dependencies][3]

Comment: Did you add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' to your project level gradle file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Error:Could not find com.google.gms: google-services: 3.0.0.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554608/how-to-fix-errorcould-not-find-com-google-gms-google-services-3-0-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your project module `gradle`

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

add `dependencies`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: added all this still

Comment: have you downloaded JSON from firebase project.?

Comment: are you still getting error.? do add class path in project module gradle.!